# C#: WndProc() and IntPtr types - how to handle it correctly? Does IntPtr type require special care?

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

I have `WndProc(Message m)` override. This obviously is called a lot. Let's say I want some messages to be marked as "handled". So I should set `Result` to 1. But `Result` property is `IntPtr`. What happens when `m.Result = new IntPtr(1)` is executed? Each call would allocate memory for one `Int32` value? What would happen if I made a static `IntPtr` variable and set it to `new IntPtr(1)`?

What is the most correct way of doing this?

Then I want to compare `m.LParam` to known value. It's also `IntPtr` and I can do it several ways:

```
if (m.LParam == (IntPtr)0x0001) ...
if ((int)m.LParam == 0x0001) ...
if (m.LParam == myStaticIntPtr1) ...
```

What are the costs of such comparisons? What happens on low level during above 3? `Message` type is not disposable. So I think I can safely omit passing it to `base.WndProc()`, am I right? Nothing needs to be done with it when I just want to discard the message?

Bonus question: I'm not sure, but I think I've seen `DllImport`s on pinvoke.net where `IntPtr`s present in MSDN documentation were changed to just `int`s. Possible? Does it work? What happens? Implicit conversion?

BTW, `IntPtr` is a managed type, right? So if I don't call unmanaged code nor have disposable types used - no need to dispose anything?

Comment: You are *massively* overthinking this. These are built-in, fundamental types; memory allocation is not costly. Furthermore, in this case, you are setting the value of a field in a structure, so the memory has already been allocated. All of these operations are virtually free. And they are all equivalent performance-wise. Semantically, prefer casting constants to IntPtr, rather than casting IntPtrs to ints.

Comment: IntPtr is a 32 bit integer pointing to an unmanaged object.  The unmanaged object is in shared memory (static) and is not on the execution stack like managed objects.  It should not make a difference if you use IntPtr or int, except a pointer is not signed so uint would be better.  (IntPtr)0x0001 doesn't make any sense since it would point to memory location 0x0001.

Comment: Also, you've asked way too many questions in one question here. Trying to answer some of those briefly...no, you should always pass messages on to the base class's window procedure. No, DllImport signatures that use int for pointer types are wrong and broken; don't do that. Yes, IntPtr is a managed type, but the CLR marshaller recognizes it and marshals such values properly as pointers. But they are still pointers to unmanaged objects, so those unmanaged objects need to be disposed/deleted/freed/closed as the documentation requires.

Comment: If you're ready to do micro optimizing (assuming you're not falling into the trap of premature optimization) you can use [MeasureIt](https://measureitdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Better to ask, than to guess ;) I was not sure if I'm doing it right. I'm not sure if micro-optimization is needed there. Probably not. Proper thread synchronization has way more impact on control responsiveness, since the control is multi-threaded.

Comment: Hmm, that will be a problem. In Win32, all UI is supposed to run on a single thread, known as the UI thread. Controls should never be multi-threaded.

Comment: @jdweng oh my, what you said is *completely* wrong. `IntPtr` is just a struct which has the size of a native pointer (so it's 64 bit on x64 and 32 bit on x86), and that's it. It can be used just like any other value, not necessarily as a pointer like its name suggests.

Comment: @CodyGray Of course it IS a problem :) A lot of voodoo was required to synchronize the threads. The control is a Chromium web browser, it supports singe and multi-threaded message loop. It's works faster with multi-threaded one. It took me 3 days to make it fast and stable. The thing I needed was additional touch gesture support. Done, works, case closed ;)

Answer (score 1):

`IntPtr` is a value type, and does not incur **any** memory allocation - it's either on the stack or a part of another type's memory structure. In C# the `new` operator is used for both value and reference types, which may be confusing if you come from a C++ background. You can even write `new int()` and again there won't be any allocation.

In addition, casting it to an `Int32` (`int` in C#) can yield wrong results - in a 64 bit process it will be the size of an `Int64` (you can check `IntPtr.Size`).

So in short, the cost of the comparison is negligible - **it's the same as comparing two integers**. You can keep the `IntPtr`s in static fields if that improves readability, but you shouldn't worry about memory.

The following are equivalent:

- `new IntPtr(1)`
- `(IntPtr)1` - there is an explicit cast operator that translates it to the above constructor

The reason this type exists is to abstract away the size of a pointer when dealing with unmanaged APIs, so you could P/Invoke into Win32 from 32- and 64-bit processes.